# Termux returns error on command: from pymongo import MongoClient

Tags: termux

I am trying to install MongoDB on Termux.
When I run command (from pymongo import MongoClient), I get error message:

> No command 'from' found

Answer (score 0):

Now this is just a BIG BIG maybe, but did you try starting python before entering python commands? **RHETORICAL QUESTION.**

RUN `python` BEFORE WRITING THE COMMAND.

If you haven't installed python, use `pkg update && pkg install python -y`